# Issue with creating promotions in Targetting option of Smart Target

Tags: smarttarget

I have installed smart target with Tridion 2013 SP1. Now I am not able to create promotions after going to Targeting option in Tridion.

"Add a new promotion" button is disable. Can anyone help me to figure out probable cause..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do not have the promotion management right which is set on the publish target. Or, there are no publication targets enabled for SmartTarget (see the same Targeting tab on the publish target).